# Return error message after saving a model with custom save() method on Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I've two models. One is a `Subscriber` and at save time I'm assigning a pool based on the number of subscribers already assigned to that pool:

```
class Subscriber(models.Model):
    pool = models.ForeignKey(Pool)
    interface = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class Pool(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Let's say that only 4 `Subscribers` can be assigned to a pool. That's why I'm overriding Subscriber's `save()` method:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.pk:
        #Look for a free Pool among the available ones
        for pool in Pool.objects.all():
            if pool.subscriber_set.count() < 4:
                self.pool = pool
                print "Assigned pool: %s" % pool.name
                super(Subscriber, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

It's working great until I run out of pools (all of them have 4 users assigned). How should I handle this from Django admin? Ideally I'd like to show some error message to the user so he can create more pools.

I would rather not move the pool assignation code to the form's `clean()` method because probably users will also be created from a different interface, not the admin GUI.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would recommend validating in both `clean()` and `save()`. The former will give you a nice error message and workflow in the admin, while the latter will make sure that `save()` itself gives an error message regardless of how you're creating the instance.

First the validation:

```
class Subscriber(models.Model):

    def clean(self)
        if not self.pk:
            if not Pool.objects.annotate(num_subscribers=Count('subscriber'))
                               .filter(num_subscribers__lt=4)
                               .exists():
                raise ValidationError('The pools are all full.')
```

This will be called automatically from the admin (see the documentation on [`ModelForm` validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#validation-on-a-modelform)). Alternatively - if you're not cleaning things outside of `ModelForm` validation - you could supply this logic in the form's `clean()` method.

Then do the same thing in the `save()` method.

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            try:
                self.pool = Pool.objects.annotate(num_subscribers=Count('subscriber'))
                                        .filter(num_subscribers__lt=4)[0]
                super(Subscriber, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            except IndexError:
                raise ValidationError(..)
```

You could instead call `self.full_clean()` inside `save()` to do the validation, but this version seems more straightforward (and is definitely more efficient).

Comment: thanks! That worked great. I only had to put the self.full_clean() after the pool assignment: According to the doc, the Model.clean_fields is called as part of full_clean and as the pool field is requiered the value has to be assigned before. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @IgnacioVerona: Good point. I just edited the answer to reflect that, and to assign the pool more efficiently (specifically, without looping). As you can see there are several good ways of achieving this...

Comment: Why is it more efficient? Will not clean be calles when saving via ModelForm ? So the same check will be made twice ?

Comment: @GonzaloA: In this example, the OP wants not only to validate but also to set a value (`self.pool`). So if you call `full_clean()` to do the validation you still have to hit the database again to actually set the value. The approach I suggested above will do both the setting and the validation in one database call.